# Best way to migrate from opencart 1.5.3 to magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, migration

Hi Magento Developers ,

I have a opencart website with,

```
60 products
555 Orders
1837 Customers
```

I'm in need to migrate entire opencart to magento, so far i've done the fronted theme. Now the biggest issue I’m facing is with database migration for products, orders, customers.

I've googled a bit and found some of solutions,

1. http://www.shopping-cart-migration.com/ An expensive premium service
2. Manually creating and mapping all together. (An time taking process but not sure whether this will work or not)

So do you guys have any other way to solve this database migration from opencart to magento ?

Please share your ideas.

Comment: if you can create the script to import data form Opencart to Magento then it's very simple way

Comment: @Keyul Shah It's not so easy to do in magento, coz magento follows EAV database model.

Comment: Yes Easy Magento Use EAV Model I know But when you got row data like name, desc, price then you can save product using as per Magento Standards using Magento Standards

Comment: @Serpyre Read the topic before it commenting on any. I didn't asked about the cost cutting way. All i asked is the different way's of doing the same.

Answer (score 1):

The most cost effective way would be to simply not worry about your old orders and just import customers and products.

If you do need orders there are a couple of modules that will import orders, at least one that is free. The process is fairly slow and you have to set it up.

If you want everything all at once I would recommend using Cart2Cart. It is quick, effective and easy to use.